# The mapping @manyToOne doesn't return Foreign Key JSON

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a mapping for two entities, `ProfileGroup` and `User`, where the User has a relationament `@OneToMany` to ProfileGroups;

The problem is that return of my requisitation, does not show the Foreign key fk_user of table ProfileGroup in the JSON requisitation for all ProfileGroups.

ProfileGroup

```
    public class ProfileGroup {
...     
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="fk_user_creator")
        @JsonBackReference
        private User userCreator;

...
```

User

```
public class User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userCreator")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ProfileGroup> profileGroups;
```

The Resource class:

```
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> listAll(){
        List<ProfileGroup> profileGroupsReturned = profileGroupRepository.findAll();

        return !profileGroupsReturned.isEmpty() ? ResponseEntity.ok(profileGroupsReturned) : ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
```

And the result JSON: (DONT APPEAR THE FK_USER)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Calango Careta",
        "description": "Cadê? cadê? Nós somos a Orquestra Camaleônica do Calango Careta!!!!!!!!",
        "founded": "2015-04-12",
        "registered": "2018-11-14",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tropicaos",
        "description": "",
        "founded": "2018-01-20",
        "registered": "2018-11-14",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Capivara Brass Band",
        "description": "",
        "founded": "2016-08-24",
        "registered": "2018-11-14",
        "active": false
    }
]
```

Any idea? What's wrong?

thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**
this is what JsonBackReference annotation does , though since you have bidirectional relation if you remove it you will end up with infinite loop when trying to serialize your objects.

**Solution**

- If you really do not need to have bidirectional relation just get rid
  of it by removeing on of the relations (either OnToMany or ManyToOne)
- you can swap the BackReference to User but then you will not have the
  group serialized in your user
- you can use @JsonIgnore which will do the same as the previous
  solution
- you can start using separate DTO for serializing instead of
  serializing your entity and there you can control the relation and
  make sure you do not hit infinite serializing loop
- you can use json property filters to ignore the property which will
  cause the infinite loop, so forexample if you are serializing user ,
  you can specify on profile property to ignore the user inside it so
  you break the loop

Comment: Thank you so mutch @Amer Qarabsa! Your informations help me to understand and solve this question.

I put the `@JsonIgnore` for this moment, but next time i go make a Filter for best find the profiles.